# Buefy Vue2 select does not react on input event

Tags: vue.js, select, vuejs2, buefy

I have a code where I need to iterate over the array of objects and every one of them have a b-select inside. This select should react on input event but it deos nothing. The event is triggered on the first render but then it stops trigger event at all. Also the :v-model does not react on role change. The value is still the same.

```
<div v-for="(inv, index) in pendingInvitations" :key="index" class="columns is-desktop">
    <div class="column is-4">{{inv.email}}</div>
    <div class="column is-4">
        <b-field class="mb-5">
            <b-select v-if="invitationRoles" 
                    :input="changeInvitationRole(index)"                                                 
                    :model="pendingInvitations[index].role" 
                    :placeholder="$t('company.users.invitation.roles-placeholder')">
                <option v-for="(value, key) in invitationRoles"
                        :key="key"
                        :value="value">
                    {{ value }}
                </option>
            </b-select>
        </b-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

The changeInvitationRole method looks like

```
changeInvitationRole(index){
    console.log('aaaaaaa');  // Does not trigger after the change
    console.log(index);
},
```

InvitationRoles looks like

```
{
    aaa:"aaa",
    bbb:"bbb",
    ccc:"ccc",
    user:"user,
}
```

PendingInvitations array looks like

```
[
    {
        active:1,
        deleted:0
        email:"xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
        id:8
        role:"user"
        token:"7l1nd8j2re"
    }
]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

":" is bind sign. Methods are using "@" sign. Change to @input.native

Comment: I found it right after I wrote the question. The problem was in the :model. It should be v-model. Thanks.